# What are the correct sentences? 'Since' with present simple and present perfect

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses

a) It is ages since we went to the cinema.

b) It has been ages since we went to the cinema.

c) We haven’t been to the cinema for ages.

I think b and c are correct. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, people say it each way.

Here’s a [site](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/its-long-time-its-been-a-long-time.165615/) on which people are discussing a question like yours, and the discussion seems to end in agreement that “It’s been a long time since…” and “It’s a long time since…” are interchangeable. None of the participants in that discussion cites any authority, but they are themselves some evidence that people do speak in these ways.

**THE 'HAS BEEN' CONSTRUCTION**

- A June 16, 1983 [article](https://www.lrb.co.uk/v05/n11/richard-rorty/against-belatedness) in the London Review of Books called Against Belatedness, by Richard Rorty, remarks “It **has been** a long time since anybody with pretensions to historical depth has agreed with Macaulay about Bacon."
- A July 13, 2010 [article](https://newrepublic.com/article/76235/the-prose-and-the-passion) in the New Republic called The Prose and the Passion, by Adam Kirsch, also uses "It **has been** a long time since..."

Somehow, that "has been" construction seems to me both more logical and more idiomatic than "is." However, one does find the "is" construction among careful writers.

**THE 'IS' CONSTRUCTION**

- “Very true,” agreed the Wizard. “But it **is** a long time since I have had any sleep, and I’m tired. So I think I shall lie down upon one of these hard glass benches and take a nap.” - From [Dorothy and the Wizard in Oz](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/22566/22566-h/22566-h.htm), by L. Frank Baum. CHAPTER 5: “DOROTHY PICKS THE PRINCESS”
- The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/long_time_no_see) defines the expression “long time no see” with the words “It **is** a long time since we last met (used as a greeting).”

So it must be admitted that careful writers use both constructions.